# Pandas subset based on groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, subset

I've below pandas dataframe.

```
   a   b
0  5  10
1  6  12
2  9   4
3  8   3
4  3   6
5  2   7
6  4   5
```

Now I wish to get the last subset which doesn't match condition df.a > df.b. Means if we create a new column in order to understand this better then it will look like below.

```
   a   b     c
0  5  10  Down
1  6  12  Down
2  9   4    Up
3  8   3    Up
4  3   6  Down
5  2   7  Down
6  4   5  Down
```

From the above, I wish to get the last subset of df.c having the same value "Down", which means output will have last three rows as shown below.

```
   a   b     c
4  3   6  Down
5  2   7  Down
6  4   5  Down
```

I wrote below code. But I'm clueless after this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 10], [6, 12], [9, 4], [8, 3], [3, 6], [2, 7], [4, 5]], columns=["a", "b"])
df['c'] = np.where(df.a > df.b,'Up','Down')
print(df)
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: I see reaccepting, so please test with real data carefully, because I think solution generally not working

Comment: I if no `Down` group it fail. I think if not defaultindex it fail

Comment: Problem is with `idxmax`, it working wrongly(select first value) if no match

Comment: Also fail is first group is also last group

Comment: E.g. test `df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 10], [6, 12], [9, 4], [8, 3]], columns=["a", "b"])`

Comment: E.g. test `df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 10], [6, 12], [9, 4], [8, 3], [3, 6], [2, 7], [4, 5],[9, 4], [8, 3], [3, 6], [2, 7], [4, 5]], columns=["a", "b"])`

Comment: I suggest you go with @jezrael answer because it's more generalized.

Comment: Thanks jezrael. I also thought the same..

Comment: The exact solution for me is.. df['d'] = df['c'].ne(df['c'].shift()).cumsum() and df = df[df.d == df.d.max()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for get last group of filled by `Down` values is first get groups for each consecutive values `s` created by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then filter it by `Down` values with mask created by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), get maximal value for last group and last filter original `s` value for final mask - last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['c'].ne(df['c'].shift()).cumsum()
m = df['c'].eq('Down')
df = df[s.eq(s[m].max())]
print (df)
   a  b     c
4  3  6  Down
5  2  7  Down
6  4  5  Down
```

**Details**:

```
print (s)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
Name: c, dtype: int32
```

---

```
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: c, dtype: bool

print (s[m])
0    1
1    1
4    3
5    3
6    3
Name: c, dtype: int32

print (s[m].max())
3

print (s.eq(s[m].max()))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one with [`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups):

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups
m = df[df['c'].eq('Down')]
df.loc[[list(i) for i in consecutive_groups(m.index)][-1]] #-1 takes the last group
```

---

```
   a  b     c
4  3  6  Down
5  2  7  Down
6  4  5  Down
```

Where :

```
[list(i) for i in consecutive_groups(m.index)]
```

Outputs:

```
[[0, 1], [4, 5, 6]]
```